# How do you store an integer while in a foreach loop

Tags: php, loops

This may be simple to some of you guys but im a novice coder. How do i make this foreach loop terminate after i loops. The number keeps resetting as it loops through another condition. There are multiple a's. About 100 so it i never gets up to 250.

```
$i = 0;

foreach ($a as $b) {
   //do function

   i++;

   if (i == 250)
   {
     exit;
   }
}
```

Comment: Why does it need to execute 250 times?  Seems to me the purpose of a foreach is to eliminate the need for counters and such.

Comment: That... should work, as far as I can tell.

Comment: A function buried inside of the loop needs to terminate the whole application if the limit is reached.

Comment: I did a echo of i, but it kept resetting and counting from 1 when it hit a new a as it is for each a as b.

Answer (score 6):

You're missing a "$" sign on two of your "i"s. It should be:

```
$i = 0;

foreach ($a as $b) {
   //do function

   $i++;

   if ($i == 250)
   {
     exit;
   }
}
```

Comment: And the increment too. Good catch, I missed it myself. Used to C.

Answer (score 3):

$i should not reset, because it was declared outside of the for-loop. However, there in a syntax error within that snippet:

```
$i = 0;

foreach($a as $b)
{
   // do something with $b
   if(++$i == 250) exit;
}
```

Comment: da5ids's comment is the same: You've just forgotten to add the '$' symbol in front of the 'i' variable within the forloop, so you weren't actually changing the value of '$i'...

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the dollar sign ($) before your variable i within the loop:

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($a as $b)
{  
    //do function  
    $i++;    
    if ($i == 250)
    {
        exit; // or break;
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If $a only contains an array of about 100 elements as you said, then there is no need to check that $i is 250.  After the code has gone through all the elemnents in $a, then the foreach loop will exit and you will go on to the next code.

```
foreach($a as $b) {
  echo $b . '<br />';
}

echo 'Loop has finished';
```

If you are looking to keep count, you should use for instead:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($a); $i++) {
  echo 'Element ' . $i . ' is ' . $a[$i] . '<br />';
  if ($i == 250) {
    break; // this will exit the loop
  }
}

echo 'Loop has finished';
```